# How to post csv file to slack using curl?

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

I am using the below curl command to post CSV file to slack. The command is executing successfully, but   I am not able to see CSV file updating in slack. Can someone let me know what is the issue with below command ?

```
curl -s -F title='Batch status of XXXX ' -F initial_comment='Batch Status report XXXXX'  --form-string channels=xxxx-monitoring   -F file=@etest.csv -F filename=etest.csv   -F token=xxxxx   https://xxxx.slack.com/archives/Cxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the command es executing successfully. You just don't see any error message, because you are using the silent option (`-s`).

The issue with your command is that you are not calling the correct API endpoint.

For [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) the correct endpoint is `https://slack.com/api/files.upload` (not `https://xxxx.slack.com/archives/Cxxxxxx`)

This should work:

```
curl -F title='Batch status of XXXX ' -F initial_comment='Batch Status report XXXXX'  --form-string channels=xxxx-monitoring   -F file=@etest.csv -F filename=etest.csv   -F token=xxxxx   https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

Comment: I am getting the below error --{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"files:write:user","provided":"identify,incoming-webhook"}

Comment: That error means, that the token you are using does not have the required scope (`files:write:user`). You need to first add the missing scope and then re-install the corresponding Slack app to activate. Then it should work.